# Why I am getting Authorization Error when using the youtube api with oauth

Tags: python, api, youtube

I am trying to use the youtube api to add create a playlist in my account. I have created my oauth credentials, I didn't change anything setting up the consent screen. I have downloaded the secret json file.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert?apix=true), below it is how you create a new playlist:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.playlists.insert
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.playlists().insert(
        part="snippet,status",
        body={
          "snippet": {
            "title": "Sample playlist created via API",
            "description": "This is a sample playlist description.",
            "tags": [
              "sample playlist",
              "API call"
            ],
            "defaultLanguage": "en"
          },
          "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "private"
          }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have run it without changing anything, and I am at the point `"Please visit this URL to authorize this application"`.

When I click it, I get a new tab with the following error:

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: redirect_uri
```

Sometimes, executing the exact same thing I get:

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: client_id
```

The missing required parameters that are mentioned in the errors seem to be filled in the url for the authorization.

Any ideas what;s happening ?

Comment: When you create your app (API), don't you have to create a `redirect_uri` config?

Comment: @Torxed At the secret_file.json there is the following key: "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]

Comment: Ah, so you had it. Not that I had many ideas to begin with but I'm out of ideas heh.

Comment: @Torxed What I realised is that the url shown in jupyter lab displays & as &amp; when print is used. If I use the console the url is displayed properly. Maybe there is a setting in jupyter lab to properly show urls. Any ideas ?

Comment: Oh noo idea, for these very reasons I never use IDE's or automation environments. Console + texteditor all the way. Try it out and see if it makes a difference :)